# How to find how many times I'd have to run a scraper to collect entire set by random subsets

Tags: probability

So I have sets of data with several hundred entries, but can only go through 100 randomly at a time. What I'm trying to figure out is how many times I'd have to run a scraper to get almost all entries. I can't quite find what I need through searching, though I know it's a probability problem ..  Any help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: You should specify your question in more quantitative detail for a precise answer. In the meanwhile, search for _coupon collector problem_.

Comment: You could also search the site for questions involving the coupon collector problem

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't figure out how exactly to describe this issue.